# Configure redirectUrl for signInWithRedirect()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm writing a POC JavaScript app using GoogleAuthProvider and need to change the redirectUrl so the callback goes to a different location.

I see redirectUrl going across on the query string, but can't find anywhere in the API to set it. I tried putting it in `firebase.initilizeApp(config)` but that didn't work. I don't see it in GoogleAuthProvider or `auth().signInWithRedirect()`.

I also went into the Firebase console and don't see anywhere to configure it there.

So is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Firebase Authentication handles the server-side redirect behind the scenes and should on the client get your users back to the page they started from automatically, even when you use `signInWithRedirect`. Can you describe the actual problem you have that would cause the need for this parameter?

Comment: My first POC was with Azure AD which returned you to the original URL but with the query string parameters removed. My Sencha Ext JS JavaScript app has both development and production builds which loads different scripts for development if '?development' is on the query string. What would happen is I would start with my development app, redirect to AD login, then end up on my production app which I can't debug. So with AD I what to change the redirectUrl to another page then return to the original page with the query string.

Firebase keeps the QS but wondering if redirectUrl is possible?

Comment: Since I ran out of characters, since Firebase returns you to the original URL with the query string intact, not being able to do a custom redirectUrl is probably a non-issue. Since I have to do it with Azure AD I was asking about it with Firebase so my code flow can be consistent.